# "the provider did not return a providermanifesttoken" using Oracle MangedDataAccess with EF 6 Code First

Tags: c#, oracle11g, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, oracle-manageddataaccess

I have an web application that was using oracle 11g, EF 5 code first and system.data.oracleclient.

So now, It was upgraded to EF 6 and Oracle Managed Data Access.

The ODP .Net is installed. This error happens only when I am using TNS in connection string. If I write the full connection string, with TNS, it works fine.

My connection string is:

```
<add name="CoreDbContext" connectionString="data source=DBCONN;password=TIS;user id=TIS" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, I have reinstalled the Oracle data provider and it worked fine.

Comment: I used NuGet and uninstalled both Oracle and Oracle.EntityFramework. Then reinstalled both and it worked for me.